# converting binary to string, only converting first 8 bits

Tags: c++, string, loops, binary

Using C++. My code asks the user for a string input, prints that string back to them in binary, prompts them to enter some binary, and then converts that binary back to a string. When testing the code I enter a string like "bed" and reenter the binary in returns me. When it converts the binary back I will end up with "bbb" so its returning the first 8 bits * the segments of 8.

Any suggestions on fixing this? It seems like my a variable is starting back to 0. I've tried for( int a = z;.....) and this just prints the first 8 bits only( "bed" -> binary -> "b")

My code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <bitset>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
string stuff;
cout << "type some stuff :" << endl;
getline(cin, stuff);
int convert = 0, 
toconvert = 0;


for(int i = 0; i < stuff.length(); i++)
{
    cout << bitset<8>(stuff.at(i));

}

string retype;
cout << "type in some sweet binary:" << endl;
getline(cin, retype);
char mycharacter;
for(int z = 0; z < retype.length(); z += 8 )
{

        for(int a = 0; a < retype.length(); a++)

        {
            if (retype.at(a) == '1' )
            {


            convert = (int)pow( 2,( 7- a));

                toconvert = toconvert + convert;  

            }

            else if (retype.at(a) == '0')

            {
                toconvert = toconvert + 0;  
            }

            else
            {       
                cout << "you did not type binary, try again" << endl;
            }        
}
        mycharacter = char(toconvert);
        cout << mycharacter;
        toconvert = 0;      

}

cout << "  " << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::bitset` is a template and the argument for that template is the amount of bits.. You have `std::bitset<8>`. Why not just use `std::bitset` to do the conversion from and to anyway? Ex: http://ideone.com/vWI3K6

Comment: I think you may want to consider how your input, in values eventually converted to 8-bits-per-char, needs to be converted back to *8-bits-per-char*. And your loop limits need work. It start "back at zero" because that is precisely where your `a` loop takes it; *repeatedly*. Not really sure what you're trying to accomplish with `toconvert = toconvert + 0; ` either.

Comment: toconvert = toconvert + 0; makes it so the decimal I'm trying to sum does only has a value added to it for the 1's present in the entry. I attempted to address a being set back to zero by setting a = z on the inner loop to no avail.

Comment: Yeah, i get that, I would have done `else if (retype.at(...) != '0') {cerr <<"msg";}`. [something like this](http://ideone.com/uJxjtc), (though to be frank I would have done most of this differently).

Comment: WhozCraig, your changes work great! I will study the code to figure out why you did what you did and why it works. Thank you very much.